# Jackson error : unacceptable character '' (0x0) special characters are not allowed

Tags: java, regex, jackson, yaml

I'm trying to parse yaml data using jackson from MySQL but I get error saying there is a special character. I get error something like this :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: special characters are not allowed 
[Source: java.io.StringReader@5528a42c; line: 13, column: 68] (through reference chain: com.app.ResultContentModel["opinion"])
...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: special characters are not allowed
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5528a42c; line: 13, column: 68]
...
Caused by: unacceptable character '' (0x0) special characters are not allowed
in "'reader'", position 1027
```

My dependencies file look like this :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to replace it using regex :

```
Pattern nonASCII = Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\x7f]");//("[^\\x00-\\x7f]");
resultContent = Normalizer.normalize(nonASCII.matcher(resultContent).replaceAll("");
ResultContentModel rc = mapper.readValue(resultContent, ResultContentModel.class);
```

But still didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Try  chaining another replacement - `.replaceAll("[\\x00-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x20]+", "")`

Comment: It failed to even recognize the yaml data.

Comment: If that is a feedback on my comment, then note that the regex is not to match any YAML data, but to remove unwanted control chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I get this error when trying to chain your regex (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.bdg.model.resultContent] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method)

Comment: Combining two regexps into 1: `Pattern nonASCII = Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\x7f]+|[\\x00-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x20]+");`

Comment: Owh sorry my bad @WiktorStribiżew, still the same simple type error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post some YAML data that is causing this as well as the class you are attempting to deserialize the data into.  If the data or class is sensitive or very large, create a simplified example class and data that are triggering the issue.  This will allow answerers to copy and paste the class and data into an IDE to recreate and debug the issue.

Comment: Since @WiktorStribiżew s first comment fixed the error in the question and you get a completely different error now, please open a new question.

Comment: Does it mean the regex works for you? I can post if you do not have any unwelcome chars in the data after using my suggestion.

Comment: well after using your regex it makes the yaml "beauty" dissapear, I think that what makes me get the "simple error", I'm still learning about regex so I still don't know which part remove the enter/tab/space.

Comment: Please use `@`+username to notify a user of your comment. You want to know how to remove LF (newline), TAB and SP (space) symbols with regeX? I left these out on purpose in the pattern above. Do you want to include them? Just use `Pattern nonASCII = Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\x7f]+|[\\x00-\\x20]+");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to match any non-ASCII + all characters with hex codes from `00` till `20` (space).

Use

```
Pattern nonASCII = Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\x7f]+|[\\x00-\\x20]+");
```

The `\x00-\x20` will match all the control characters you need to remove and the `[^\x00-\x7f]` will match non-ASCII chars.

The `+` quantifier will match 1 or more occurrences, so as to remove/replace the character chunks matched in one go.